# Why is my Delta kitchen faucet dripping? How can I fix it?

Tags: leak, kitchens, faucet

I installed a [Delta Ashton](http://www.deltafaucet.com/kitchen/details/19922-sssd-dst.html) single pull faucet in my kitchen about a year ago. Recently, it has started leaking both at the pivot and at the spray selector on the wand (red areas circled in the image below). If it matters, the faucet seems to only leak after the water has been running for a few minutes and we have moderately hard water.

Does anyone know what the source of the dripping is? How can I fix it? Some of the other "facuet leak" questions mention a cartridge. I don't even know if this faucet has one.

[image: Faucet drip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the internal hose, and inspect it for damage. Also inspect the connection between the hose and the wand head.